# How to trim lines includes specific string with sed

Tags: regex, linux

I have separate files include path string for each like ;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user@yahoo.com/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user@hotmail.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user@abc.xxx.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user55@ccc.com/
```

what i want to trim lines like;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@hotmail/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@abc/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user55@ccc.com/
```

I am almost be able to achieve with below (all strings are in separate files but at the 15th line)

```
sed -r '15s!@[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^.@]+@[^.]+).*$!\1/!g' $file
```

however, i have an issue with dot part that cuts it as ;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55@ccc/
```

instead, it should have been;

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user55@ccc/
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pattern with three capture groups should do what you need. The first group will capture the portion behind the initial `@` (as a group we omit from the replacement), the second group will include the `/dddd/` portion, and the third being the complete `user@somewhere` with a prepended `.`

```
's!(@.+\..+)(/.+/)(.+@.+)!\2.\3!g'
```

Depending on your version of bash you could use it like this:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's!(@.+\..+)(/.+/)(.+@.+)!\2.\3!g' $file
```

↳ *(GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)*

```
sed -i bak -E 's!(@.+\..+)(/.+/)(.+@.+)!\2.\3!g' $file
```

↳ *GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)*

result:

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@yahoo.com/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@hotmail.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@abc.xxx.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user55@ccc.com/
```

It's a little unclear if you want to keep the full extension on the end of the last match; if not sed is probably not the best choice because it can't do look-ahead, look-behind assertions, nor toggle greedy in any straight-forward manner. In the case that's a deal breaker, you could use this pattern on one of many other avenues:

```
(@.+\..+)(/.+/)(.+@.+?)(\..*/)
```

result:

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@yahoo
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@hotmail
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user@abc
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user55@ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use two matches:

```
sed -E 's/(.*?\..*?)\/(.*?)@\1/\1\/\2/g'
```

- Regex: `(.*?\..*?)\/(.*?)@\1`
- Replacement: `\1\/\2`
- Flags: `g` (Global)

Result:

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo.com/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@hotmail.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@abc.xxx.co.uk/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55@ccc.com/
```

---

```
sed -E 's/(\w+@\w+)[\w\.]*/\1/g'
```

- Regex: `(\w+@\w+)[\w\.]*`
- Replacement: `\1`
- Flags: `g` (Global)

Result:

```
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@yahoo/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@hotmail/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user@abc/
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55@ccc/
```

---

If the `-E` switch is not available on your version of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), then you might have to use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).

Example:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?\..*?)\/(.*?)@\1/\1\/\2/g' -i filename.ext
```

---

If I try this in bash, I get the following result:

```
root@home [~]# echo "path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user55/" | sed -E 's/(.*?\..*?)\/(.*?)@\1/\1\/\2/g'
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55/
root@home [~]# echo "path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55/" | sed -E 's/(\w+@\w+)[\w\.]*/\1/g'
path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/user55/
```

Comment: sed -E 's/(.*?\..*?)\/(.*?)@\1/\1\/\2/g' output is "path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccc.com/dddd/user55/" an  "sed -E 's/(\w+@\w+)[\w\.]*/\1/g'" output is "path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user@ccccom/dddd/user55@ccccom/"

Comment: I noticed you are using `-r` in your original post, maybe your `sed` does not have the `-E` switch available? Can you confirm?

Comment: sed -r 's!@[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^@]+@[^.]+).*$!\1/!g' file  is just fine. i just need to add dot like "path = /aaa/bbb/ccc.com/user/dddd/.user55@ccc/"